# timestamp converts to wrong date php

Tags: php, timestamp, epoch

```
<?php
$timestamp=1466679909936;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$timestamp);//output: 48447-03-27 22:05:36
?>
```

output should be:  2016-06-23 1:05:09

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This timestamp is in milliseconds, not in seconds so divide it by 1000

Comment: The correct timestamp for that date is `1466636709`, where are you getting that timestamp from?